# Why does my ads script does not work when inserted dynamically via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this amazon ads script that when included like this works perfectly fine.

```
<div id="asdf">
  <script type="text/javascript">amzn_assoc_ad_type ="responsive_search_widget"; amzn_assoc_tracking_id ="murkind-21"; amzn_assoc_marketplace ="amazon"; amzn_assoc_region ="IN"; amzn_assoc_placement =""; amzn_assoc_search_type = "search_widget";amzn_assoc_width ="auto"; amzn_assoc_height ="auto"; amzn_assoc_default_search_category =""; amzn_assoc_default_search_key ="m40x";amzn_assoc_theme ="light"; amzn_assoc_bg_color ="FFFFFF"; </script><script src="//z-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&Operation=GetScript&ID=OneJS&WS=1&Marketplace=IN"></script>
</div>
```

When I inspect the `asdf` element I see this

```
<div id="asdf">
  <script type="text/javascript">amzn_assoc_ad_type ="responsive_search_widget"; amzn_assoc_tracking_id ="murkind-21"; amzn_assoc_marketplace ="amazon"; amzn_assoc_region ="IN"; amzn_assoc_placement =""; amzn_assoc_search_type = "search_widget";amzn_assoc_width ="auto"; amzn_assoc_height ="auto"; amzn_assoc_default_search_category =""; amzn_assoc_default_search_key ="m40x";amzn_assoc_theme ="light"; amzn_assoc_bg_color ="FFFFFF"; </script>
  <script src="//z-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&amp;Operation=GetScript&amp;ID=OneJS&amp;WS=1&amp;Marketplace=IN"></script>
  <div id="amzn_assoc_ad_div_adunit_0"><!--inside here there are multiple other divs and a stylesheet--></div>
</div>
```

However if I leave the asdf div empty and then insert the script via jquery like below

```
<div id="asdf"></div>
```

```js
$("#asdf").html('<script type="text/javascript">amzn_assoc_ad_type ="responsive_search_widget"; amzn_assoc_tracking_id ="murkind-21"; amzn_assoc_marketplace ="amazon"; amzn_assoc_region ="IN"; amzn_assoc_placement =""; amzn_assoc_search_type = "search_widget";amzn_assoc_width ="auto"; amzn_assoc_height ="auto"; amzn_assoc_default_search_category =""; amzn_assoc_default_search_key ="m40x";amzn_assoc_theme ="light"; amzn_assoc_bg_color ="FFFFFF"; <\/script><script src="//z-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&Operation=GetScript&ID=OneJS&WS=1&Marketplace=IN"><\/script>');
```

I get the error

> Error : adType is not defined render   @   onejs?MarketPlace=US:1  (anonymous) @   q?ServiceVersion=200…=1&Marketplace=IN:1

And when I inspect the asdf element I see this

```
<div id="asdf">
  <script type="text/javascript">amzn_assoc_ad_type ="responsive_search_widget"; amzn_assoc_tracking_id ="murkind-21"; amzn_assoc_marketplace ="amazon"; amzn_assoc_region ="IN"; amzn_assoc_placement =""; amzn_assoc_search_type = "search_widget";amzn_assoc_width ="auto"; amzn_assoc_height ="auto"; amzn_assoc_default_search_category =""; amzn_assoc_default_search_key ="m40x";amzn_assoc_theme ="light"; amzn_assoc_bg_color ="FFFFFF"; </script>
  <script src="//z-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&amp;Operation=GetScript&amp;ID=OneJS&amp;WS=1&amp;Marketplace=IN"></script>
</div>
```

The difference I can see between the two is that in the first one which works the `<div id="amzn_assoc_ad_div_adunit_0">` is created in which there are multiple other divs whereas in the second one it isn't there. I cant do it the first way because I will later have to inject the script based on an ajax request.

Comment: thanks for the edits Rory, would appreciate it if you could tell me how I could get this to work

Comment: because in first case you create div manually and load script whenever div create but in second case you add script after div created thats why its not load inside div properly.

Comment: not sure I follow you Bhargav, why would that be a problem?

Comment: because div created first and than only script tag write on that not load Murali